# How to perform UPDATE + Mathematical function into empty column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, math, amazon-redshift

I need perform a simple subtraction on a column and insert the new value into a new table.column.

The table are structured as such, logic is not a column it is what I want to do mathematically just for time not the date, dropping it is fine as well but the date and time are in the same cell stuck together:

```
Table A         
    A       Time                      (Logic)
1   aaa   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS         (row2 - row1)
2   aaa   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS         (row3-row2)
3   aaa   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS         (row4-row3)


Table B         
        A         new_time  
    1   aaa       insert logic row 1    
    2   aaa       insert logic row 2    
    3   aaa       insert logic row 3
```

**Question is how do I subtract each row for tableA.time from the next row and UPDATE that value into tableB.new_time?**

-----EDIT----

@klin

this is my script modeled after yours:

```
update tableB
set new_time = tableA.time
from (
    select tableA.A- lead(tableA.A) over (order by tableB.B) 
    from tableA
    ) tableA.A
where tableB.a = tableA.A
```

Error Message:

```
SQL Error [500310] [42P10]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: subquery in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level;
```

Comment: There is not row0, with what do you want to subtract from row1? More importantly, the difference between timestamps is an interval. How are you going to store that interval in the same column that previously held timestamps?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the SELECT statement was just me messing around, hence I said it was on paper, I am coming from a MySql background so was trying to map it out.

Comment: @redneb my apologies should start with row 1 i will update. I do not need to store it in the same column I need to UPDATE tableB.new_time with the difference of time from tableA.time

Hope this helps

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just ignore my SQL statement for now, its me just trying to work through some logic. I need to run an UPDATE on tableB.new_time with difference of time from tableA.Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery as a data source in `update`. Example:

```
create table table_a (id int primary key, t timestamp);
insert into table_a values
(1, '2016-09-01'), (2, '2016-09-02'), (3, '2016-09-04');

create table table_b (id int primary key, i interval);
insert into table_b values
(1, null), (2, null), (3, null);

update table_b b
set i = a.i
from (
    select id, t - lead(t) over (order by id) i
    from table_a
    ) a
where b.id = a.id;

select * from table_b;

 id |    i    
----+---------
  1 | -1 days
  2 | -2 days
  3 | 
(3 rows)
```

One-letter aliases are handy but sometimes not quite clear. The same query with more informative aliases:

```
update table_b as alias_b
set i = subquery.i
from (
    select id, t - lead(t) over (order by id) i
    from table_a
    ) as subquery
where alias_b.id = subquery.id;
```

Comment: I have been trying to work your UPDATE statement but I am getting confused with all the extra names for the tables. I made an edit with my script modeled after yours and error message I get.

Comment: thank you for the cleanup, I have another problem if you can help. Your query works correctly, but since date AND time are included in the same cell is there any way to first slice out the date and just do the calculations on the time?

Comment: You can cast timestamp to time, e.g. `select '2016-10-01 12:12:12'::time` yields `'12:12:12'` (alternative notation `select time '2016-10-01 12:12:12'`).